# MaskedEditText cannot get text

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

Sorry for my English.
I am using the  library [MaskedEditText](https://github.com/toshikurauchi/MaskedEditText). Everything works fine, but I can get text(only text).
Example: I have XML:

```
<br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText 
    android:id="@+id/phoneNumber"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:inputType="number"
    mask:mask="(###) ###-##-##"
>
</br.com.sapereaude.maskedEditText.MaskedEditText>
```

If the user enters text: `(111) 111-11-11`,
I should get only `1111111111`.

Below is my code

```
MaskedEditText text = (MaskedEditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Text without mask: " +
    text.getText(true), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The error: `The method getText() in the type EditText is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)`

**UPDATE**
If i use these methods:

```
Log.e("Mask ", text.getMask());
Log.e("getCharRepresentation ",
    String.valueOf(text.getCharRepresentation()));
Log.e("getCharRepresentation ", text.getText().toString());
```

Its output:

```
05-30 12:41:40.448: E/Mask(7980): (###) ###-##-##
05-30 12:41:40.448: E/getCharRepresentation(7980): #
05-30 12:41:40.448: E/getCharRepresentation(7980): (111) 111-11-11
```

Comment: try `text.getText()`?

Comment: @Gosu i update my question, its output (111) 111-11-11, i need only 1111111111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, assuming that you only have `(`, `)`, and `-` that you wish to remove..

```
String str = String.valueOf(text.getCharRepresentation());
str = str.replaceAll("\\D", ""); // Replace all non-digits
```

Here is an example:

```
public class TestReplacement {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        String str = "(111) 111-11-11";

        System.out.println("String before replacement: " + str);

        str = str.replaceAll("\\D", ""); // Replace all non-digits

        System.out.println("String after replacement: " + str);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
String before replacement: (111) 111-11-11
String after replacement: 1111111111
```

Answer (score 1):

> The error: `The method getText() in the type EditText is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)`

This says, that the Method `getText()` can't take a boolean (`true`) paramter.
Try without `true`. If that also returns the brackets and stuff check for a method added by `MaskedEditText`.

Comment: Or just leave out the true, and then use the method @Gosu suggested

Answer (score 1):

for getting text without mask and hint,

```
EditText.getRawText()
```